# Django standalone script in buildout env

Tags: python, django, buildout

Well this is quite harsh problem, "different solution proposal" is not available in current situation, so please try to help me solve this problem, not to avoid it =)

So there's a django project which uses buildout but doesn't use virtualenv (because we had problems installing fonts..). Project is working fine. Now I'm trying to implement django standalone script, and I think I have a path problem. First of all I would like introduce a structure of base dir.

```
roman% ls   
bootstrap.py    
cgi-bin             
eggs        
parts
bin
buildout.cfg
develop-eggs
lib
project

bin
|-- buildout
`-- django


roman% cd eggs 
roman% ls -h  
DateUtils-0.5.1-py2.7.egg               oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg
Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg                  pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg
South-0.7.3-py2.7.egg                   pyBarcode-0.6-py2.7.egg
collective.recipe.omelette-0.12-py2.7.egg       pycrypto-2.5-py2.7-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg
django_mptt-0.5.2-py2.7.egg             pygeoip-0.2.2-py2.7.egg
django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg           python_dateutil-2.0-py2.7.egg
django_registration-0.7-py2.7.egg           python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg
django_rosetta-0.6.5-py2.7.egg              pytz-2012b-py2.7.egg
django_social_auth-0.6.7-py2.7.egg          setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg
django_staging-0.1.0_alpha-py2.7.egg            six-1.1.0-py2.7.egg
django_tagging-0.3.1-py2.7.egg              sorl_thumbnail-11.12-py2.7.egg
django_threaded_multihost-1.4_1-py2.7.egg       unicodecsv-0.9.0-py2.7.egg
djangorecipe-1.1.2-py2.7.egg                xlwt-0.7.3-py2.7.egg
flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.7.egg           zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
html5lib-0.95-py2.7.egg                 zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.7.egg
httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg

roman% tree parts 
parts
|-- buildout
|   |-- site.py
|   |-- site.pyc
|   |-- site.pyo
|   |-- sitecustomize.py
|   |-- sitecustomize.pyc
|   `-- sitecustomize.pyo
`-- omelette
    `-- django -> /srv/xxx/eggs/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django

3 directories, 6 files
```

the standalone script is in /srv/xxx/project/app/ dir

now finally the script:

```
import os
import sys 
import time
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join( '..', '..' ))) # Project dir
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join( '..', '..', 'parts', 'omelette')))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join( '..', '..', 'eggs'))) 

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings                                                                                                                 

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings.site_nl'

from django.template.loader import render_to_string
```

If you run this script, everything works except the last line. I even can import models. Anyway when I execute this in ipython, you can navigate through autocomplete to django.template but everything that is deeper, for example django.template.loader/base/whatever - doesn't work.. last line of this script gives this error

```
roman% python email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 34, in <module>
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/template/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/template/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.template.context import Context, RequestContext, ContextPopException
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/template/context.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.http import HttpRequest
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/http/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import cookie_date
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/utils/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email.Utils import formatdate
  File "/srv/travelbird/travelbird/draaideur/email.py", line 34, in <module>
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
  File "/srv/travelbird/parts/omelette/django/template/loader.py", line 29, in <module>
    from django.template.base import Origin, Template, Context, TemplateDoesNotExist, add_to_builtins
ImportError: cannot import name Origin
```

incase you need buildout.cfg here it is..

```
[buildout]
parts = django ipython omelette
eggs =
    reportlab
    lxml
    MySQL-python
    markdown
    sorl-thumbnail
    django
    django-tagging
    django-pagination
    django-staging
    pyBarcode
    dateutils
    html5lib
    oauth2
    python-openid
    pygeoip
    django-rosetta
    django-social-auth #check
    South
    unicodecsv
    xlwt
    django-mptt
    django-registration
    django-threaded-multihost
    pycrypto
    flup
    ipython

#PIL # custom install by pip

extra-paths =

[versions]
django = 1.3.1

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
project = project
projectegg = project
settings = settings
extra-paths =
    ${buildout:extra-paths}
    ${buildout:directory}/project

[ipython]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ipython

[omelette]
recipe = collective.recipe.omelette
eggs =
    django

ignore-develop = true
```

sys.path -->

```
In [16]: sys.path
Out[16]: 
['/srv/xxx/project/settings/../../lib',
 '',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.15-py2.7-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.3-py2.7-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-freebsd8',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/srv/xxx/project',
 '/srv/xxx',
 '/srv/xxx/parts/omelette',
 '/srv/xxx/eggs']
```

I would like to mention that I tried to install django from ports (package manager), and I checked the sys.path, yes it was using installed version, still get exactly the same error. although half of django path's works..

And about settings. we have 5 settings files for each language site. so it's:  settings.site_nl . If I forgot to add something please leave message in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you're handling sys.path manually in your script, you're using buildout wrong. Buildout handles all your installed python eggs for you. If django runs OK, your script should too.

What you're missing is a buildout part that creates more scripts in your bin directory. For that, add an extra part to buildout (and add that `console_scripts` to your `parts =` list):

```
[console_scripts]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

After running buildout, this gives you a whole lot of extra scripts in your `bin/` directory. Amongst others `bin/python`. Look in it and you'll see that it contains exactly the right `sys.path` stuff, preconfigured for you by buildout.

(After you got it running, you might want to look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe/1.1.2 , that's a buildout recipe that makes it even more comfortable to install Django).